# PrimeNG: Simple Button Dropdown without MenuModel

Tags: angular, primeng

I need a very simple dropdown with custom items in the dropdown body. The SplitButton in PrimeNG needs an item-array from which the body will be created automatically: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/splitbutton
But however I want to create all selectable options with custom html code exactly like in NG-Bootstrap: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/dropdown-basic.ts

Is there a possibility to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-select

https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates

This has possibility to insert a complete template of html code as a dropdown item.

Comment: no it shouldn't be a select container. It should be a button with an expanding dropdown body